# R loop to pull data based on condition from another column

Tags: r, function, sapply

I have this dataframe, when V1 is = 1, I will get the data from column Yi1, if V1 = 0, I will get the data from column Yi0.  I want to get the different of the mean for each of the column, V1:V22704156.

I coded some items out, but not sure which part is error?

[image]

```
pm <- function(x) {
  a = combined_df[combined_df$x == 0, combined_df$Yi0]
  b = combined_df[combined_df$x == 1, combined_df$Yi1]
  return(mean(a) - mean(b))
}

sapply(combined_df[,5:7], FUN=pm)
```

Will be thankful for any help!

Error prompt is "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NAargument is not numeric or logical: returning NAargument is not numeric or logical: returning NAargument is not numeric or logical: returning NAV1 V2
NA NA "

Comment: you should present a better example and a data.frame that could be created from the code and not an image. Also the sentence "different of the mean for each of the column" is not clear.  IF I UNDERSTAND CORRECTLY this look to me as simple subsetting problem. Imagine your data.frame is called "df" then your solution is mean(df[df$Treatment == 0, "Y0"]) - mean(df[df$Treatment == 1, "Y1"])

Comment: Hi Gerald, thanks for the comment. I am not trying to extract based on Treatment column, I am extracting based on the V1, V2 ... V22704156

Comment: Can you add a simplified example and the expected result in your example?